# Slim 3 App returns 404 with existing endpoints

Tags: slim, slim-3

[image]I am using Slim Framework 3 in my project. The app has two (2) endpoints which are `/numbers` and `/` and they are both accessible when running the app on my local machine. The problem is that `/numbers` returns `404` on the remote/hosted server which is on digital ocean. What does not make sense is that `/` still works fine. The remote server is running on `Ubuntu 16.04 x64` and I am using `PHP 7` on both servers. I have uploaded the screenshot of the files on the server, which are exactly the same as the ones on the local machine

```
$app->get('/', function($request, $response, $args){

    $payload = ['1'=>'root', '2'=>'admin'];
    return $response->withStatus(200)->withJson($payload);
});

$app->get('/numbers', function($request, $response, $args){

    $payload = ['1'=>'One', '2'=>'Two'];
    return $response->withStatus(200)->withJson($payload);
});
```

Comment: Is it a custom 404 or just the default 404 page by your web server? Are you sure you have put `.htaccess` file there as well?

Comment: It's default 404 and yes I think I put `.htaccess` at the right place because I uploaded everything as it was from local machine to the digital ocean

Comment: Could you please make sure of that? Just check if the file is there. Because some tools used to upload files just might ignore dot files by default.

Comment: I just confirmed, and yes it has been uploaded. I would upload the screenshot of the files on the server if I knew how to do so. I am looking into uploading the screenshot

Comment: What does visiting `yourdomain.com/index.php/numbers` give you?

Comment: It gives 404 default error message

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158734/discussion-between-mohale-and-nima).